# Create alphanumeric list based on varying cell value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

So I have a set of data with around 120 parents each with between 8-16 child data entries. Each parent is indexed by number and I'm trying to get each child to have the parents number followed by an alphabetic character e.g.

```
A    B
58   Parent entry
58A  Child 1
58B  Child 2
```

It currently looks like (with child entries index cells being blank):

```
A   B
58  Parent entry
    Child entry 1
    Child entry 2
```

How would I go about automatically (I guess via VBA) filling in the appropriate index for each child entry based on their respective parent entry (both parent and child are in the same column). Note: Each parent has a different number of children entries.

Comment: So that's what you *want* it too look like, what does it currently look like?

Comment: I'll edit accordingly

Answer (score 3):

Doable without VBA. I split the process down across a few columns. Formulas below:

[image]

B2: `=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(":",A2)),"Child","Parent")` 
C2: `=IF(B2="Parent",LEFT(A2,SEARCH(":",A2)-1),C1)` 
D2: `=IF(B2="Child",C2&CHAR(63+COUNTIF($C$2:C2,C2)),C2)`

---

Requested explanation of D2 formula above:

`COUNTIF($C$2:C2,C2)` counts how many times the value in C2 has been found in column C *up to the current row* (current being the row with the formula in)

So for example. `D4` can count three 58s from `C2:C4`, similarly `D8` can count seven 58s in `C2:C8`.

Consider `D4` again, it counts three 58s so the formula is equivalent to this:

```
=IF(B4="Child",C4&CHAR(63+3),C4)
```

`CHAR(65)` returns `A` up to `CHAR(90)` returning `Z`. So in this case it follows that `CHAR(66)` returns `B`. Hence:

```
=IF(B4="Child",C4&"B",C4)
```

Comment: This is great, however I have a blank row in between each parent/child set that serves as a total further along the row, which is consequently being falsely flagged as a child.

Comment: Just tried to implement this and realised I explained poorly: column A is a single number for the parent or blank for the child (the index), column B onwards is the parent/child data. There is no ":" in the index. I've edited the question accordingly

Comment: I fixed the previous issue, now working on the total row being flagged as a child problem. Could you explain how your formula in D2 works please?

Comment: Solved it, thanks for the help. Would still be interested in learning how your D2 formula works.

Comment: Hi @AaronGretton, glad it worked for you eventually (sorry I was away when you were having problems). I've updated my answer to include some explanation of the `D2` formula

Answer (score 0):

Building on @CallumDA answer, using the same format as him the formulas I used in the end were:

B2: `=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A7)),"Total",IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("",A6)),"Child","Parent"))`

C2: `=IF(B6="Total","",IF(B6="Parent",A6,C5))`

D2: `=IF(B6="Child",C6&CHAR(63+COUNTIF($C$6:C6,C6)),C6)`

Answer (score 0):

assuming your data starts at cell A1

```
Sub AddParentNumber()    
    With Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Resize(, 1)
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="
        With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
            .FormulaR1C1 = "= concatenate(OFFSET(R1C,MATCH(1,R1C:R[-1]C,-1)-1,0), UNICHAR(64+row()-MATCH(1,R1C:R[-1]C,-1)))"
            .value = .value
        End With
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```